# Is there a way to cut a large ggplot in two/three (y axis) to acomodate for printer (multiple pdf page)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a really large data set and the scatter plot I made with ggplot2 is really large too. I want to avoid text superposition for easy reading.

How to cut this chart in two or three to acomodate for printer ?

Thank you,

Comment: You can convert your plot to an image of appropriate size and then print.

Comment: But always in one paper sheat. Of course I can do this but the text will be very small. Is there a way to choose how many y axis dot per page ?